# How do I install an open source django-application?

Tags: django

I want to install an existing django app, djangopeople.net. The code is at http://github.com/simonw/djangopeople.net.

I installed django and I understand how to create a new django project.

But how do you deploy an existing app? I know how this works in Rails or Symfony, but I don't really get the django concept here.

Where do I put the files? Which scripts do I run?
Thanks for the steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why is this any different from deploying your own applications? Just put them somewhere in your PYTHONPATH and set up mod_wsgi or whatever to serve them.

Comment: FWIW, the Apache/mod_wsgi package ignores PYTHONPATH as Apache isn't started up as the user but normally from an init script as root. In Apache/mod_wsgi you use WSGIPythonPath if using embedded mode, python-path option to WSGIDaemonProcess if using daemon mode, or simply add additional directories from the WSGI script itself. For more details see 'http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/VirtualEnvironments'.

Comment: Thanks, got it up and running. Pythonpath was in fact new to me